# Fedora 23: Properly recreating /home partition and integrating it into an exisiting installation?

Tags: linux, partitioning, fedora, data-recovery, file-permissions

I used a btrfs raid 1 for my /home partition, but unfortunately the file system destroyed itself. '/' is on a seperate drive. Now I want to recreate the /home partition for my user (this time using mdadm and ext4).

How do I recreate the /home partition so all permissions are/will be set accordingly (Especially regarding SELinux)? Should/Can I use the Fedora 23 graphical installer to recreate it properly and how do I go about doing so?
Will those user-specific configuration files be regenerated or how do I get them to do so? What do I have to modify on my root partition to get everything to work? I just try to avoid a situation, where, I will constantly have SELinux/permission problems and have to constantly find and copy config files

Comment: Consider using ZFS instead. It has every feature you wanted from btrfs _and more_, and unlike btrfs it won't eat your data for breakfast one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a partition for it.
2. Lookup partition id (sudo blkid)
3. Add uuid to /etc/fstab
   (UUID=xxx-xxxxx-xxxxx   /media/home    ext4          nodev,nosuid       0       2)
   exchange X's with the id from 2.
4. Create mount point at ex: /home
5. reload updated fstab: sudo mount -a

https://www.maketecheasier.com/move-home-folder-ubuntu/

Comment: What is with LVM and mdadm as well as permissions and SELinux?